# Java EE version of an EAR

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, ear

How can I know the Java EE version of a generated EAR from Maven build? I built an EAR using Maven build and added J2ee dependency as

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.ibm.websphere</groupId>
      <artifactId>j2ee</artifactId>
      <version>6.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

in the pom.xml.
How can I make sure the generated EAR is of Java EE version 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing to things here - dependencies and packaging.

First, if you plan to work with WebSphere it is better to install WebSphere dependencies into your local repository, rather than add different various dependencies (You don't need to install dependencies for WebSphere Liberty as they are available remotely). You can find installation poms for specific WAS versions here: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/maven/repository/com/ibm/tools/target/

Then you add dependency like this in your web or ejb project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.tools.target</groupId>
    <artifactId>was</artifactId>
    <version>8.5.5</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Or use one of the preconfigured archetypes available in the [IBM WebSphere repository](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/maven/repository) for creating web/ejb apps for WebSphere.

For packaging you use `maven-ear-plugin` like below. For Java EE ear key setting is that `version` element inside `configuration`. You need to provide that one as default is 1.3.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId> 
  <version>2.8</version> 
  <configuration>
      <generateApplicationXml>false</generateApplicationXml> 
      <version>6</version> 
      <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir> 
      <archive>
          <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor> 
      </archive>
      <modules>
        <webModule>
           <groupId>helloApp</groupId> 
           <artifactId>helloWeb</artifactId> 
           <contextRoot>/helloWeb</contextRoot> 
        </webModule>
     </modules>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you very much clearing my understanding.

I would like get more clarity on how to identify the J2EE version of an EAR deployed.
J2EE version configured in maven is J2EE 5, but I am deploying the generated EAR in WAS V8 which uses J2EE 6 profile.
So can I expect the J2EE 6 features will be available for me, like CDI 1.0?

Comment: @sreejithsasidharan  If EAR has explicitly in `application.xml` version 5 not 6, then Java EE 6 features will rather not work (I didn't test that, but I would expect that). So if you need Java EE 6 features like CDI then you need to fix version configured in maven. It might work, if there is no `application.xml` at all, then it should treat application as v6, but you will have to check DD for modules.

Comment: Thank you Gas. I
n my case, maven-ear configuration pointing version 5. 

<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
        <configuration>
        <version>5</version>
  
And EAR don't have application.xml added, so EAR might be using J2EE V6 profile in WAS 8. I am able to use CDI to inject EJB session beans to my REST API layer using @Inject and the REST API is not an EJB session bean.